# Generate change log with minimal SQL calls?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run a lot of update statements from code, and we have a requirement to summarize what changed for every operation for an audit log.

The update basically persists an entire graph consisting of dozens of tables to SQL Server.  Right now, before we begin, we collect the data from all the tables, assemble the graph(s) as a "before" picture, apply the updates, then re-collect the data from all the tables, re-assemble the graph(s) for the "after", serialize the before and after graph(s) to JSON, then create a message to an ESB queue for an off-process consumer to crunch through the graphs, identify the deltas, and update the audit log.  All the sql operations occur in a single transaction.

Needless to say, this is an expensive and time-consuming process.

I've been playing with the OUTPUT directive in T-SQL, I like the idea of getting the results of the operation in the same command as the update, but it seems to have some limitations.  For example, ideally, it'd be great if I could get the INSERTED and DELETED result sets back at the same time, but there doesn't seem to be a concept of UNION between the two tablesets, so that gets unwieldy very quickly.  Also, because the updates don't actually modify every column, I can't take the changes I made and compare them to the DELETED, since we'd show deltas for columns we didn't change.

...but maybe I'm missing some syntax with the OUTPUT command, or I'm not using it correctly, so I figured I'd ask the SO community.

What is the most efficient way to collect the deltas of an update operation in SQL Server?  The goal is to minimize the calls to SQL Server, and collect the minimum necessary amount of information for writing an accurate audit log, without writing a bunch of custom code for every single operation.

Comment: Are your columns nullable?

Comment: @SqlZim some are, some aren't.  These tables are the products of years of various developers, you can imagine there's not a lot of adherence to a particular standard.

Comment: Have you looked at [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server)? It's available in all versions and editions since 2005. It allows you to ask for the changed records per table since the last time you checked, with the change reason and (optionally) values. Check [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server#Obtain).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have not... I will look at this, but at first glance this looks like a SQL Server-based solution, so I expect that would meet with resistance with the Powers That Be, who want code-based solutions.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs ??? You did use the `sql-server` tags ??? And this *is* a code-based solution. Ultra-accelerated since it's based on an existing SQL Server feature. If you mean *client-side only*, how would that ever work with even moderate data if you have to *always* pull the entire database into memory instead of the 10 rows that changed?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if OUTPUT (or something along those lines) returned a delta set, that would be ideal.  I am unaware of such a mechanism, or if can be practically created... but just because I'm unaware of it, doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  I'm hoping for a pleasant surprise about a SQL Server feature I don't know about.  But... failing that, other options are definitely worth considering.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs  - Could you show me the format of your change log table - I guess, current value, date time and action(insert/update/delete)?

Comment: @gotqn there is no change log table... when the audit processing service finishes its deltas, it summarizes the changes into a human-readable sentence or paragraph, and then ships it to a document database for end-users to read (it's a horrible solution, but I'm trying to keep the scope narrow because I will certainly not be allowed to re-engineer the whole system)

Comment: Can we stored the `OUTPUT` details in a temporary table and perform select from it, in order to get the information in a format suitable for the user?

Comment: @gotqn in theory, yes... but I don't see how that would help?

Comment: Also, I see you use `SQL Server 2014`, but if you are able to update to `SQL Server 2016` you can use temporal tables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) - they are created easily per table and manged by the SQL Server Engine, so you will get your history with minimum effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157575/discussion-between-gotqn-and-jeremy-holovacs).